jxls template: delete cell value if value already exists in column
I have some data from a SQL table exported through a dynamic list from ReportServer. I can use JXLS to style the report. JXLS is a friendly frontend for Apache POI, I don't know more than that.
There is a command called forEach, we use that to tell the excel template what to do for each row.
I want to handle rows that have repeat ids differently from previous instances of that row, so that name and id only appear once but terms can be multiple
Standard output:



name
id
term




taz
1
2020


taz
1
2021


taz
1
2022


bob
2
2019


bob
2
2020



desired output:



name
id
term




taz
1
2020



2021




2022



bob
2
2019



2020





in first comment i put jx:area(lastCell = "C3"),
in second comment i put jx:each( items="${rows}" var="row" lastCell="C3" varStatus="status" )
in cells themselves, i plan to do something like
headers are name, id, term
and row is ${row.name}, ${row.id}, ${row.term}
I'm not sure how to run excel formula to check if value already exists in prev cell.
Finally I wanted to do some special styling to insert a special row between different names, maybe a nice bright yellow row to show a total or something
Well, I simply don't understand how to run JXLS and ReportServer that well, so not much has been tried at all, beyond the simplest template even simpler than shown in their examples.

I was able to sort of solve this in an excel template by making the first sheet hold all rows, the second sheet uses excel formula to decide whether to keep an id/name. I'm not sure this is a robust solution, though, and it doesn't answer my question if my goal was to do it in one sheet, since I created a dependency on the data sheet rather than doing it in-place.
Does anyone have a suggestion for this as a single sheet only method?
here's how I did the two sheet method, note this is psuedocode since otherwise i'd need to attach the excel workbook
Dynamic List Sheet
A1.Comment = jx:each (items="data" var="row" lastCell="C2")
A2.Comment = jx:each(items="data" var="row" lastCell="C2")
A2.Value = ${row.ID}
B2.Value = ${row.NAME}
C2.Value = ${row.TERM}
Compute Sheet
A1.Comment = jx:each (items="data" var="row" lastCell="C2")
A2.Comment = jx:area(lastCell="C2")
A2.Formula=IF(COUNTIF('Dynamic list'!$A$2:A2, 'Dynamic list'!A2) > 1, "",  'Dynamic list'!A2)
B2.Formula=IF(COUNTIF('Dynamic list'!$A$2:B2, 'Dynamic list'!B2) > 1, "",  'Dynamic list'!B2)
C2.Formula='Dynamic list'!C2```

